# Azure Webjob Issue

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am having an unexpected error.
The azure webjob is behaving differently when i run it manually from sever and when it is triggered automatically at the configured time.I am using .net mvc app as my webapp.
2 issues.
1.Why this is happening and what is the solution?
2.Is my webjob depend on webapp ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is my Web-Job depend on webapp?

- Web Jobs are built on Azure App Service
- `WebJobs` are stand-alone applications that can be executed within the context of an Azure App service.They run independently of the main application.
- `WebJobs` is determined by what you do with App Service.
- It does depend on the size/Pricing tier of your app service that your Web-Job is running on.
- If you’re using queue to receive messages and update, the latency will depend on the underlying SKU (App Service plan). If required quota or capacity for your app is full, then the `Web-Jobs` and the `web apps` would fail.
- The configuration settings required for the `Web-Job` are done at the `Web app` level.

***Please check the below Steps to Create a WebJob.***

Create a Web app with .NET runtime in `Australia East` region, the `webjob` will be deployed in the same app in Australia east region.

[image]

- Create storage account and 2 queues (queue, processed).
  [image]
- When new message arrives in `queue` storage the `Web-Job` trigger will run and post the message in `processed` queue.
- Copy the connection string from `Storage Account` and paste it in the `appsettings.json` in your code.

[image]

[image]

- Add a new message in the queue in the storage account.
  [image]

Let’s run the `Web job` project locally and check if this queue message gets added to the processed queue.

Run the `Web Job` from Visual Studio and check the queue in `Portal` => `Storage Account`

The message got removed from `queue` storage and was transferred to `processed`.

[image]
[image]

***Deploy Web-job as a trigger and run the Web-job from Azure Portal.***

Select `Webjob` type as triggered and click on Publish
[image]

***Deployed WebApp as Web Job***
[image]

Web-job is scheduled and is running automatically.
[image]

- In the App Service, click on `Diagnose and solve problems` – Checkout the tile for `Diagnostic Tools` >`Availability and Performance`. Review the WebJob details.
- Check whether your `Web-Job` is running on multiple instances of `Web apps` or single instance.
- Make sure your Web Job is not missing any files and deployed properly in Azure Portal.
  [image]
- When a continuous job is set to singleton, it will run on a single instance. By default, it runs on all instances.
- For `Scheduled Web jobs`, `Always On` must be enabled in the Azure App service to prevent the web job from being idle.
  [image]